# Remove XMLRPC to avoid vulnerability exploit

Tags: security

How is `xmlrpc.php` from Drupal core affecting functionality?

Given the fact that a vulnerability was discovered for it, details in this [article](http://mashable.com/2014/08/06/wordpress-xml-blowup-dos/?utm_cid=mash-com-fb-main-link)

- is it safe to remove `xmlrpc.php` file?
- Is it bad practice? If so, why?
- Is there any way to neutralize this security risk without removing
  this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it safe to remove xmlrpc.php file?

Yes, if you're not expecting anyone to use it.

> Is it bad practice? If so, why?

Could be construed as such; any change to core creates an additional step when updating (I'm sure we're all aware of the dangers of 'hacking core' by now, but if not: [Never Hack Core](https://www.drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)).

> Is there any way to neutralize this security risk without removing this file?

Update your core to 7.31, where the vulnerability [has been fixed](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-7.31-release-notes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am well aware that `hacking` core is something to be avoided, and I know you should take extra measures when updating. One thing I forgot to ask is, if that file is removed, will it solve the security threat?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the vulnerability was only in that file, so yes, getting rid of it should solve the problem

Comment: Actually strike that, other files have also changed related to the limit for ddos - so upgrading is the safest option

Comment: Removing `xmlrpc.php` and ditching some `.txt` files is less hacky than actually changing `robots.txt` and `.htaccess`, which I often find necessary already in moderately complex projects.